# Hide UnHide Macros Excel VBA

Tags: vba, hide

I am trying to make two macros: one that hides rows based on a criterion in a certain column, and another that unhides rows based on the same criterion.

Here is the code for the first macro, which works fine:

```
Sub hide()
    Dim item As Variant

    For Each item In Range("f:f")
        If item = "complete" Then item.EntireRow.hidden = True
    Next
End Sub
```

It's the second macro, the unhiding one, that doesn't work for me. Excel tells me it cannot run the macro or all macros have been disabled. Here is the code for the second macro:

```
Sub Unhide()
    Dim item As Variant

    For Each item In Range("f:f")
        If item = "complete" Then
            item.EntireRow.hidden = False
    Next
End Sub
```

If it's relevant, each macro is located in its own module.

Comment: Would anything here help you? http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/01/12/hide-an-excel-macro/

Comment: Why not use the built-in AutoFilter functions?

Answer (score 1):

In your second macro you have a missing `End If`:

```
Sub Unhide()
    Dim item As Variant

    For Each item In Range("f:f")
        If item = "complete" Then
            item.EntireRow.hidden = False
        End If   ' <<<<<<<<<<<<< missing
    Next
End Sub
```

Add that, and you're good to go.

The difference between the first and the second Sub is this: in the first, you put the statement right after the `Then`. In the second, you go to a new line. Unlike in C, you need to indicate with an `End If` where the group of statements ends.

Normally you don't just get a "can't run code" error, but an actual `Next without For` type of error (that's what happened when I pasted your code and tried to compile it).

In future, click `Debug->Compile VBA Project` before trying to run your code, and heed the error messages. It can be quite a time saver.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just step through all the used rows in the spreadsheet and check the value of Column F?

```
Sub hide()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "complete" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Further it would probably be cleaner to just combine the hide and unhide...

```
Sub hide(ByVal isHide As Boolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "complete" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.hidden = isHide
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested - The code is fine.
You do need an `End If` in your *Unhide* procedure though, right before `Next`.